# Как увеличивать число после запятой в цикле?

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, for, double

У меня есть цикл по **Double**:

```
for (double db = 10.00; db < 1000.99; db++)
{
Console.WriteLine(db);
}
```

Все работает хорошо, **НО** при выводе я получаю вот так:

```
10.00
11.00
12.00
13.00
```

Почему при этом не прибавляются цифры после запятой (**сотые**), чтобы было вот так (когда сотые дойдут до **99**, увеличивались целые):

```
10.01
10.02
10.03
10.04
.....
10.99
11.00
11.01
```

Есть ли на это какое-нибудь решение? Никогда с таким не сталкивался вообще.

Comment: `db++` это тоже самое что и `db+=1`

Comment: что бы добится добавления одной сотой, нужно прибавлять одну сотую: `db+=0.01`

Comment: Будьте любезны, скажите пожалуйста где это в коде правильно воткнуть?

Comment: `for (double db = 10.00; db < 1000.99; db+=0.01)`

Comment: советую почитать [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.6.php)

Comment: Гениально! Можете оформить ответ кодом, я сразу помечу как ответ?

Comment: Я кстати сегодня читал этот пост, но из-за того что там такого примера нет, да и делать так можно, я и не сообразил.

Comment: Ну это уже совсем. По сути вопрос звучит так: "Я использую инкремент `++`, почему он прибавляет по `1`, а не по `0.01`? Потому что инкремент по определению это делает, вот почему )

Comment: Ахах! Точно. Я кстати еще кое-чего не могу сделать, можно ли отсчет до нового целого числа сделать на одной строке, ну например: 11.10 - 1.99, а как будет 12.00 и до следующего целого, то отсчет будет на новой строке?

Comment: @CrazyElf, похоже, многие считают `; i++` частью синтаксиса цикла, а не просто выражением, которое выполняется после завершения итерации

Comment: @Grundy - я тоже из многих, нет ну реально, я никогда не использовал вариативность в этом ))

Comment: @Grundy Ну я как-то так и понял. Просто видят часто используемую конструкцию, а что она и в других местах бывает и что-то вообще значит - ещё не знают )

Comment: @Malcolm Ваш дополнительный вопрос непонятен, увы )

Comment: @CrazyElf, он хочет выводить на одной строке все и по условию добавлять перевод строки

Comment: @Malcolm добавил, то что вы просили

Comment: @KuzCode я имел ввиду что то такое, сотые считаются на одной строке до 99, далее появляется другое число на следующей строке и снова до 99, ща покажу:

`Считаем: 10.99
Считаем: 11.56`

Чтобы считались так, например; берем число 10, у него на конце считаются только сотые, затем когда значение достигает 99, делаем перевод строки и начинаем число 11, которое также считает до 99, а потом переводим на 12 и т.д.

Comment: Меня терзает кто мог этому вопросу поставить плюс....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (double db = 10.00; db < 1000.99; db += 0.01)
{
    Console.WriteLine(db);
}
```

> кстати еще кое-чего не могу сделать, можно ли отсчет до нового целого числа сделать на одной строке

```
for (double db = 10.00; db < 1000.99; db += 0.01)
{
    if (Math.Round(db, 3) % 1 == 0 && db != 10)
        Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write(Math.Round(db, 3) + " ");
}
```